# How can I allow the end user to add products used in a Bill of Material?

Tags: php

This is my first time posting on this site though I've found a lot of great answers here in the past for various other questions. I'm excited to see how it works out!

I currently have a rather large PHP system where salesmen enter building details into a form and it builds a bill of materials (BOM) based on their inputs. Currently if they want to add any new materials into the system I have to do it because the calculations for getting the quantities of each item often depend on the attributes of other items in the system and I don't know how to give this control to the user.

For example, when the quote is generated to calculate the BOM, it iterates over each material in the database and fetches the quantity calculation based on the ID. The quantity calculation is hard coded into the PHP and could be something like this:

```
case (self::slidingTecScrews) :
                    $quantity = 0;
                    $buffer = 1.03;
                    $screwsPerBox = 500;

                    for ($i = 0; $i < count(json_decode($this->slidingQuantities, true)); $i++)
                        $quantity += ($this->getSlidingDoorWidths($i) / 2 + 1) * $this->getSlidingDoorQuantities($i) * 5 * ceil($this->getSlidingDoorWidths($i) / 3) * $this->getSlidingDoorQuantities($i); // for all doors

                    $quantity *= $buffer; // add buffer for extra screws

                    if ($quantity > 0)
                        $quantity += $screwsPerBox - ($quantity % $screwsPerBox); // round up to nearest full box

                    $quantities[] = floor($quantity);
                    break;
```

In this example I get the quantity of Sliding Door Tec Screws and I run a calculation of how many I need per sliding door, then multiply it by the quantity of sliding doors to get the total. Then I add in a buffer because the crew is always dropping some on the ground, then I round it up to a full box. I have absolutely no idea how I would build an interface to allow one of the users to add in a product and assign this calculation for the quantity. For good measure here's another random quantity calculation:

```
case (self::whiteCaulking) :
                    $quantity = ceil((
                        $this->getTotalQuantityManDoors(true) +
                        $this->getTotalQuantityWindows(true)) *
                        .75
                    );

                    $quantities[] = $quantity;
                    break;
```

This one passes a variable into the quantity of doors / windows to specify whether or not it should include customer supplied doors into the calculation. Sometimes the door is added to the quote but the customer may want to supply it themselves and therefore we need to order the extra trims (and white caulk) but don't want to factor the door into the total material pricing. Here we use 3/4 of a tube of caulking per door / window.

Sometimes it will use the quantity of doors in the calculation but only if they are insulated, or only if they're more than 12 feet high. Sometimes it'll add a product based on every 10 square feet of wall light in a building, it could be based on almost anything.

Getting the quantity and per-item cost of everything in the BOM allows me to show the actual build cost for the structure and then apply a markup to get the selling price. Thanks a lot.

It's a system with many lines of code, probably close to a million or even more. I guess not that large in the database though, only 400 items and 10 users. We have 60,000 quotes in there though.

Most parts have a per-unit price associated with them, some have a per-linear-foot price and 2x4 have a board-foot and price-per-k which give their prices with some math. When the BOM is built, I store each product along with their attributes (width, length, quantity, customer-supplied.....) in a match_quote_product table. It's the calculation to get the length, width, quantity which I'm trying to give the end user control of.

Creating a new part is complicated, I add an entry into the building_products table in the database and then assign a variable to the ID in the code. Then I put the variable into the switch statement like I have here and build the quantity calculation manually. It takes quite a while to add a new product and I have to get the sales guy to build the entire quantity calculation for me before I can add it. Today I was asked to add lock sets as an item and the calculation is thankfully very simple, just 1 lock set per door.

Comment: All very interesting, but I am finding it difficult to see an actual question. _Apart from the obvious hidden question of can you do it for me_ although I am still not exactly sure what IT is

Comment: Sorry, my main question is how I would build the logic which would allow the end user to add a new product and associate a quantity calculation with it, instead of me having to hard code the quantity calculation as I am doing here.

How did I get the byte-order-mark tag? That's weird, I remember typing BOM for bill of materials, it must have assumed I meant that.

It's a system with many lines of code, probably close to a million or even more. I guess not that large in the database though, only 400 items and 10 users. We have 60,000 quotes in there though.

Comment: All that data should live in the part record. Or records associates with part records. Any answer to this really depends on how you store part information

Comment: Most parts have a per-unit price associated with them, some have a per-linear-foot price and 2x4 have a board-foot and price-per-k which give their prices with some math. When the BOM is built, I store each product along with their attributes (width, length, quantity, customer-supplied.....) in a match_quote_product table. It's the calculation to get the length, width, quantity which I'm trying to give the end user control of.

Comment: I removed it now. Thanks.

Comment: @RyanVincent Woops sorry, I removed it from the Title, missed it in the Tag List

Comment: So how do you create a new part/parts on the database currently

Comment: Creating a new part is complicated, I add an entry into the building_products table in the database and then assign a variable to the ID in the code. Then I put the variable into the switch statement like I have here and build the quantity calculation manually. It takes quite a while to add a new product and I have to get the sales guy to build the entire quantity calculation for me before I can add it. Today I was asked to add lock sets as an item and the calculation is thankfully very simple, just 1 lock set per door.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite know how this works, first time user of the site. I'll edit the question and add it now. Thanks.